# Javascript Prototype Best Practice Event Handlers

Tags: javascript, event-handling, prototypejs

Hi this question is more a consulting of best practice, Sometimes when I'm building a complete ajax application I usually add elements dynamically for example. When you'r adding a list of items, I do something like:

```
var template = new Template("<li id='list#{id}'>#{value}</li>");
var arrayTemplate = [];
arrayOfItem.each(function(item, index){
   arrayTemplate.push(template.evaluate( id : index, value : item))
});
```

after this two options add the list via "update" or "insert"

----- `$("elementToUpdate").update("<ul>" + arrayTemplate.join("") + "</ul">);`

**the question is**

how can I add the event handler without repeat the process of read the array, this is because if you try add a Event before the update or insert you will get an Error because the element isn't still on the DOM.

so what I'm doing by now is after insert or update:

```
arrayOfItem.each(function(item, index){
   $("list" + index).observe("click", function(){
     alert("I see the world");
   })
});
```

so the question is exist a better way to doing this??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I post this question in Prototype Mail list and this is the answer

Hi, 
If you really want to watch each individual `li` directly, then what 
you have seems perfectly straightforward. But in that situation, 
barring a really good reason to do it that way, I wouldn't use a 
handler on each `li`; I'd listen for clicks on the elementToUpdate (or 
the `ul` within it) instead with just a single handler:

```
    $("elementToUpdate").observe("click", function(event) { 
        var li; 
        // Find out which `li` was clicked: 
        li = event.findElement("li"); 
        if (li) { 
            // Do something with the `li` 
        } 
    }); 
Prototype 1.7 has a new feature to simplify that a bit: 
    $("elementToUpdate").on("click", "li", function(event, li) { 
        // Do something with the `li`;  note it's given as the second 
        // argument to the function 
    });
```

...where behind the scenes, Prototype is basically doing what I did 
above. You'll want the first version if you're still using 1.6 (and 
since 1.7 is still at RC1, I expect you probably are).

### HTH,

T.J. Crowder 
Independent Software Consultant 
tj / crowder software / com 
www.crowdersoftware.com

the link is :http://groups.google.com/group/prototype-scriptaculous/browse_thread/thread/fec98641d72f6fea#

Comment: LOL I'm flattered to be quoted. :-) But actually, I think edwin had the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I won't do `$("list" + index)`.

There are two ways I would consider:

1) Let the click-event bubble up and catch in in $("elementToUpdate"):

```
$("elementToUpdate").observe("click", function(evt){
     alert("I see the world");
});
```

You can find which li is clicked in the evt-object.

2) Don't do repeatetly `$("list" + index)`, but just

```
$("elementToUpdate").find("li").each(...);
```

(Presuming you're using jQuery. Prototype has something similar).

Comment: it really depends on the task of the event handler. if you need to do something with the current event target (e.g. reading a value), this won't suffice, since there is no guarantee that Event.target equals the current element.

Comment: yes exactly, and the find("li") is to read the array again, so I suppose is kind the same way... but different sintax..

Comment: +1 *"Prototype has something similar"* Indeed: `Event#findElement` (http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/event/findelement/)